# Как заполнить информационное поле списка из бинарного файла?

Tags: c++, c

Прошу помощи, ибо считывание из текстового файла осилил, а бинарный никак не могу (работал только через файловый указатель в стиле С). Вот так у меня выглядит считывание из текстового файла:

```
void read_list_txt(DblList* list, int a[])
{
    int i = 0, m = 1;
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("test.txt", "rt");
    if(fp == NULL)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!\n";
        return;
    }
    char s[80];
    char* D = " "; //пробел - разделитель между числами
    char* p = new char[80]; //строка для числа в символьном виде
    fgets(s,80,fp); //считываем строку
    p = strtok(s,D); //и отделяем первое число
    while(p) //пока строка не пустая
    {
        a[i] = atoi(p); //превращение в целое число
        pushBack(list, &a[i]); //вставляем считанный элемент в список
        i++;
        p = strtok(NULL, " "); //отделяем след. число
        m++; //счетчик элементов
    }
    fclose(fp);
    delete[]p;
}
```

А вот так запись в бинарном виде:

```
void write_file_bin(DblList* list)
{
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen("list.dat", "wb");
    if(fp == 0)
    {
        cout << "Ошибка открытия файла!\n";
        return;
    }
    int z;
    Node* exem = list->head;
    while(exem)
    {
        z = *(exem->value);
        fwrite(&z, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
        exem = exem->next;
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

Comment: Какая же это *"запись в бинарном виде"*, когда там записываются строки через пробел?

Comment: я просто вообще не понимаю как работать с бинарным файлом((((

Comment: Бинарный - этого когда данные записываются напрямую. Вот а памяти лежит 4 байта `int` - в файл записываются эти четыре байта как есть.

Comment: сорри, не ту функцию вставил(

Comment: теперь всё выглядит нормально... что именно не устраивает? разве что проверки можно добавить, что `fwrite` отрабатывает нормально... ну и отдельный разговор про то с какой стороны нужно есть яйца...

Comment: я не понимаю как читать из этого файла для того чтобы заполнить список, нужен ли сдвиг по файлу, если там помимо элементов записать пробелы?

Comment: нет, там нет ни каких пробелов записаны только сами числа в двоичном представлении. каждое число занимает 4 байта (`sizeof(int)`). Читать или `fread ()`'ом или своим любимым hex-редактором. Не знаю, что именно ты имеешь в виду под «сдвигом», но `fread ()` работает с потоком, так что об этом можно думать как о том что некий «указатель чтения» сдвигается автоматически при каждом вызове.